# How to reclassify a raster into equal intervals in numpy?

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, numpy, reclassify

I want to reclassify a raster based on equal intervals. For example, if the value is in the first interval, the raster cell should be ouput as 1; the second interval should be a 2, etc. So far I've using this bit of code, which kind of works, but it doesn't handle negative numbers at all (the raster I'm using has a range of -0.4 to 1).

How can I get this working as intended?

```
import rasterio
import numpy as np

def reclass(inRaster, outRaster, mode, classes):
    with rasterio.open(inRaster) as src:
        # Read as numpy array
        array = src.read()
        profile = src.profile

        # mask nodata values
        m_array = np.ma.masked_array(array, array == np.amin(array))
        if mode == 'EqualInterval':
            amin, amax = np.amin(m_array), np.amax(m_array)
            interval = (amax - amin) / classes

            for x in range(classes):
                if x == 0:
                    m_array[np.where(m_array < interval)] = x
                else:
                    m_array[np.where((m_array >= (interval * x)) & (m_array <= (interval * (x+1))))] = x

    with rasterio.open(outRaster, 'w', **profile) as dst:
        # Write to disk
        dst.write(array)

reclass(inraster, outraster, 'EqualInterval', 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`np.linspace()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) to create the bins at the specified interval, then [`np.digitize()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) to return the indices to the appropriate bins (i.e. the class)

```
bins = np.linspace(np.min(m_array), np.max(m_array), num=classes)
i = np.digitize(data, bins)
```